# Can I use any kind of aux splitter cable for my computers surround sound output?

Tags: cable, sound-card, splitter, surround-sound

Can I use any kind of aux splitter cable for my computers surround sound output if I want to hook up multiple devices?

I'm not sure if superuser is an acceptable place to ask this type of question but yea, would like to know if they're essentially just 3 aux cables combined together or at least what the terminology for these cables is so I can search for something that will work?

I would just use the optical out but for some reason it only goes out as surround sound, maybe a driver update could fix that but windows 10 tells me it's uptodate and I'm not sure where to look for it. :(

If it doesn't work that way can anyone give me some names or recommendations for how to split them to coming out of my computer and going to multiple surround sound systems.

If anyone cares I'm using the [GA-Z170X-Gaming 7 motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128835) and here's a picture of the cables I'm asking for: (they're the same size and have the same amount of parts so I assume they're the same as aux?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a really unclear question, but if I'm reading correctly between the lines, no - you cannot get the same signal out of each of those sockets to send to multiple devices.

They are part of a single output, multichannel structure. 5.1 audio consists of left & right [green] centre & sub [orange] & rear L & R [black]

You cannot turn them all into simple stereo outputs.

You could buy a simple splitter for the stereo out [green] but by the time you split 3 ways you're going to be running out of power on the signal chain. A powered headphone splitter might do it, but it's not something I've ever tested.

(Caveat. I'm an audio engineer - but audio engineers never actually have to do this type of thing, they have expensive rigs that can route signal wherever they desire ;)

Comment: or simply separate devices. I switch between onboard sound and 2 USB audio devices depending in my needs, and if you weren't a snob there's some silly cheap options that you could hack into whatever you needed ;)'

Comment: You could do it with a soldering iron & a bit of imagination, but your impedances are going to be all over the place. Short of buying an external distribution amp, there's no good way to achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: I appreciate your inputs, though I bought 3 stereo splitters and plugged each cable into them and it seems to work perfectly so far.